# SSD model execution with Qualcomm SNPE

Tags: tensorflow, qualcomm

I try to run the SSD model on my moto Z. I want to use the SNPE SDK from Qualcomm. 
I converted the model in DLC format and I use it on my moto Z in CPU mode and it run. But in DSP mode I get that error:

```
error_code=1000; error_message=Layer is not supported. Layer FeatureExtractor/MobilenetV1/MobilenetV1/Conv2d_1_depthwise/BatchNorm/batchnorm/mul/_99__cf__102:0 of type Constant not supported by DSP runtime; error_component=Model Validation; line_no=249; thread_id=-325982924
```

It seems that a part of the model is not well supported butthe SSD seems to be runable on DSP.

Can someone help me for that?

Answer (score 0):

According to latest SNPE release note(**v1.13.0**), SSD MobileNet is only supported on **CPU and GPU** runtime.